# GNU compiler KEY_F not detecting function keys

Tags: c, curses

Basically, I have key detection for my console application, for some reason it's not detecting function keys.

Here is my code, I'm using GNU compiler on linux.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

```
        refresh();
        key = getch();
        switch(key) {
            case KEY_HOME:      key = HOME;   break;
            case KEY_END:       key = END;    break;
            case KEY_UP:        key = UP;     break;
            case KEY_DOWN:      key = DOWN;   break;
            case KEY_LEFT:      key = LEFT;   break;
            case KEY_RIGHT:     key = RIGHT;  break;
            case KEY_NPAGE:     key = PGDN;   break;
            case KEY_PPAGE:     key = PGUP;   break;
            case KEY_DC:        key = DEL;    break;
            case KEY_IC:        key = INSERT; break;
            case KEY_F(1):      key = F(1);   break;
            case KEY_F(2):      key = F(2);   break;
            case KEY_F(3):      key = F(3);   break;
            case KEY_F(4):      key = F(4);   break;
            case KEY_F(5):      key = F(5);   break;
            case KEY_F(6):      key = F(6);   break;
            case KEY_F(7):      key = F(7);   break;
            case KEY_F(8):      key = F(8);   break;
            case KEY_F(9):      key = F(9);   break;
            case KEY_F(10):     key = F(10);  break;
            case KEY_F(11):     key = F(11);  break;
            case KEY_F(12):     key = F(12);  break;
            case KEY_ENTER:     key = ENTER;  break;
            case KEY_BACKSPACE: key = BACKSPACE; break;
            default:
                //key = F(2); //For any function keypress, it jumps to default
                if (NON_ASCII(key) != 0)
                    key = UNKNOWN;
        }
```

Comment: Where are these `KEY_x` values #defined ? Are you use that `KEY_F(num)` is correct? What happens when you press a function key - what value does `key` take? Come on, this is fairly standard debugging.

Comment: Is this code for (n)curses? I think you should start debugging by examining the value of `key` when a function key is pressed and comparing it to the value you expect to be getting. I seem to remember curses having some weirdness with the function keys not meaning what you'd think they mean..

Comment: Konrad, your arrogance doesn't help me.  I've already done everything you've mentioned.

Yes it is R (<curses.h>), for some reason it returns '~' each time.  I made a seperate small app to just output return values, with that it would return 126 for each function key.  I'm pretty confused at this point.

Comment: Konrad's arrogance may not help, but his questions are germane. It would be helpful if you put the name of the library you're using for the `KEY_x` values in the question. It would also be helpful if you say what the actual value of key is when you press F keys. The compiler isn't really relevant. This looks like standard C to me.

Comment: Library for KEY_x is curses.h.  When I use a quick program I'm getting 126 returned with each getch();

Comment: @Marcin: You will get better replies if you include a short *complete, compilable* program that doesn't work. As it stands, maybe you made a mistake in the part of the program you don't show (e.g. the initialization of the ncurses library), and people are reduced to unproductive guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a curses expert, but a bit of reading man pages netted me this program:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main()
{
    int key;

    initscr(); cbreak(); noecho();

    while (1)
    {

        key = getch();
        printw ("%u\n", key);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I press an F key, I get a 3-character sequence: 27, 79, (80 + N-1) where N is the number of the F key. I think your switch will have to recognize that the key is an escape sequence and handle it specially.

**Edit:** That pattern holds only for F1-F4. F5 changes it up. You'll probably want to incorporate the F(n) macros from curses.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue, personally.

Casting the F(n) macro to a char type magically cleared the issue for me;

```
cmd = getch();
    switch(cmd){
        case 'r':
            addch('r');
            break;
        case 'w':
            addch('x');
            break;
        default:
            if(cmd == (char)KEY_F(2)){ endwin(); exit(0); }
    }
```

and the like. Worked for F2 through F10 plus F12. F's 1, 10 and 11 are "occupied" for lack of a better word on my xterm. (F1 opens the help window, F11 toggles fullscreen mode, etc.) Again, I can't emphasize enough that I couldn't begin to guess why that works.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable the "keypad" functionality of the terminal using the `keypad` function. From the keypad(3x) manual page:

> `int keypad(WINDOW *win, bool bf);`
>
> The **keypad** option enables the keypad of the user's terminal. If enabled
>   (*bf* is *TRUE*), the user can press a function key (such as an arrow key) and
>   **wgetch** returns a single value representing the function key, as in
>   **KEY_LEFT**.  If disabled (*bf* is *FALSE*), *curses* does not treat function
>   keys specially and the program has to interpret the escape sequences itself.
>   If the keypad in the terminal can be turned on (made to transmit) and off
>   (made to work locally), turning on this option causes the terminal keypad to be
>   turned on when **wgetch** is called. The default value for keypad is false.